# Trying to implement a rounded corner android 2 column gridview w/ images and text in each view

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, rounded-corners

I want the two columns to fill the space equally and the images scale within each griditem view. The images should be on top and clipped by the rounded corners. The text should be centered below the image.

Gridview code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:inputType="textFilter" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

GridItem Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/category_rounded">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/catImg"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/category_2"
        android:background="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Rounded Corner Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"></corners>

</shape>
```